# Ruby/Rails Find Object By ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an object generated from a class (Popsicles) which is being passed to another class (PopsicleProcessor) with just the ID of the Popsicle object, which is 'guaranteed' (UUID) to be unique. How can I access the Popsicle object from the PopsicleProcessor class without having to do something bad like passing the entire Popsicle object as an argument?

My application *has no database* to find these objects against, they exist purely in the memory of the application until after processing.

I really don't know how to achieve this, especially since it's being offloaded onto a Resqueue queue which will initiate an entire instance of the application again -- therefore passing the object itself would result in massive performance losses (scaled), from what I know.

In general, how can this be done (since Resqueue shouldn't make a difference at all).

I want to be able to access the objects instance variables and methods from the other class.

Here's an extraction of what I am doing now, which doesn't work.

**popsicles.rb**

```
class Popsicles

    require "securerandom"

    @someID


    def initialize params

        @someID = SecureRandom.uuid

    end

    def doSomething

        Resque.enqueue( popsicleProcessor, @someID )

    end

end
```

**popsicles_processor.rb**

```
# Worker class
class PopsiclesProcessor

  # Requires a @queue instance variable
  @queue = :popsicle_queue

  # Needs to take same argument we passed to enqueue method
  def self.perform( popsicle_id )

    # Get the object somehow

    # Now we can call other methods like changeFlavour, or whatever

  end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that your workers are running in a different process actually is relevant, because it will have its own memory space without access to the Popsicle objects created in the main application process. You would need to have some way of persisting the Popsicle objects if you just want to load them by an ID like that in another process. If you can't use a database, you'll have to serialize the object or pass the individual components of its data to the worker such that it can be reconstructed from scratch in the worker process.